# React Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some difficulties seeting validation for an Input component to be mandatory only when it was filled before, if someone can help me with this issue.

This is my component:

```
                <Input
                    type="label"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={customerData && email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label={'email'}
                    placeholder={'email'}
                    error={email ? err?.email : null}
                    invalid={!!err?.email}
                />
```

I've tried with `email ? err?.email : null` but I don't think this is correct.

Comment: const wasFilledBefore = typeof fetchedData.email === 'string' && fetchedData.email.length

Comment: @AngelZlatanov your solution is not similar with my solution? fetchedData.email.length === email and I'm not sure I understand why "typeof fetchedData.email === 'string'" ? it is a string always

Comment: Maybe the emails in your app are numbers. Sorry, my mistake. Anyways, now try using this logic to validate your input value when wasFilledBefore is true. Or specific to to your question - set the prop required={wasFilledBefore} on your input.